# why does my scoreboard not work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a system to detect right clicks using a villager and than trigger several commands. I'm using an always active repeating commandblock to start a chain of commandblocks which run the commands I need them to run. I've setup a scoreboard objective called torchLever and set it to:

```
minecraft.custom.talked_to_villager
```

so it increases everytime I talk to a villager.

I'm now trying to see if a player has the value of the scoreboard set to 1 with this command

```
/execute as @p if score @s torchLever matches 1.. run say hi
```

however this does not seem to work. I've tested a few different commands like the one in [this article](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/commands-command-blocks-and/2935886-help-testing-for-scores-in-1-13) but that doesn't work either.

How can I see if there is a player with the `torchLever` score set to 1 and than start executing a bunch of commands?

Comment: In future questions, please specify what happens. If I hadn't read the answer, I would have assumed that "it doesn't work" means that it always evaluates to true (which happens if you forget to reset the scoreboard after use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your objective is a synax error. The correct way is:

```
/scoreboard objectives add torchLever minecraft.custom:minecraft.talked_to_villager
```

As can be seen on the minecraft wiki (https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Objectives).

Secondly, your execute command is needlessly complicated. Though it may seem pretty simple at first glance, there is an even simpler and more efficient way to execute players with a score, or many scores:

```
execute as @a[scores={torchLever=1..}] run say hi
```

As can be seen on the minecraft wiki (https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Usage, scroll down to "target selector arguments).

Since you didn't specify what version of minecraft you're using, I assumed it was 1.13 Java Edition.